# How can I retrieve current terminate() handler without changing it?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, error-handling, terminate

Here's the problem. My application calls `CoCreateInstance()` to create a COM object implemented in a third-party DLL. That DLL calls `set_terminate()` to change the `terminate()` handler and passes an address of its own `terminate()` handler there.

The initial `terminate()` handler address is not saved by that library - it doesn't care and simply changes the handler and never restores it. As soon as the DLL gets unloaded its code is no longer in the process memory, so if now `terminate()` is called the program runs into undefined behavior.

I'd like to retrieve and store the address of initial `terminate()` handler to be able to restore it. How can I do it?

Comment: Could you mention what that DLL is so others can be warned as well?

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: It's domain-specific, so chances anyone 1. uses it and 2. will actually get hit by the described behaviour are negligible. Plus we're now trying to convince the vendor's support that they should fix it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Standard C++ provides no built-in way.

Of course you could just call terminate() *twice*: first time with whatever dummy handler you have (and then store handler that terminate() returned you); second -- to restore handler you've just stored ;) Simple trick.

Answer (score 2):

In C++11 you call std::get_terminate.

Answer (score 1):

You mean somthing like this:

```
terminate_handler oldHandler;

void onDllLoad()
{
    oldHandler = set_terminate (newHandler);
}

void onDllUnload()
{
    set_terminate (oldHandler);
}

void newHandler()
{
}
```