# How do I detect if a custom terminate() handler is installed?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, error-handling, terminate

My code is compiled as a Windows DLL with Visual C++. I want to log rare cases when `terminate()` is being called, so I set my `terminate()` handler in the library initialization function and the latter is called by the user code before using my library. My handler writes to the log and calls `abort()` emulating the default `terminate()` behavior.

The problem is the user code might also be written in C++ and use the very same C++ runtime version and so share the `terminate()` handler with my library. That code might also want to alter the `terminate()` handler to have their logging. So they would call `set_terminate()`, then load and initialize my library and my library would also call `set_terminate()` and override their `terminate()` handler and that will be very hard for them to detect since the `terminate()` handler is the last thing they would test I suppose.

So I want the following. Inside the library initialization function I will [retrieve the current `terminate()` handler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2200306/57428), find whether it is a standard one, then if it happens to be a non-standard one, I will store its address and later (if needed) my `terminate()` handler will write into the log and then forward the call to that custom `terminate()` handler.

Is it possible to find if a `terminate()` handler currently installed is a default one or a custom one?

Comment: If you intend on calling `abort` anyways, why don't you just always chain to the previous terminate handler instead of calling `abort`?

Comment: FWIW, I don't think chaining the previous terminate handler is a great idea. If the program dies in your code, call your handler, if in host code, call the host handler. See my RAII answer below for how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Do it via RAII like this:

```
class terminate_scope
{
public:
  terminate_function _prev;
  terminate_scope(terminate_function f = NULL){
     _prev = set_terminate(f);
  }
  ~terminate_scope(){
     set_terminate(_prev);
  }
};
```

To use:

```
void MyFunctionWantsOwnTerminateHandler(){
    terminate_scope termhandler(&OwnTerminateHandler);
    // terminate handler now set
    // All my code will use that terminate handler
    // On end of scope, previous terminate handler will be restored automatically
}
```

You can have the terminate handler chain the previous one if you are absolutely sure you need to.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN vaguely says that

> If no previous function has been set, the return value (of [`set_terminate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t6fk7h29.aspx)) may be used to restore the default behavior; this value may be NULL;

and the same for [`_get_terminate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175778.aspx). I find it not really helpful, because if the returned value is not NULL, still there is no guarantee that it is a valid `terminate` handler. One possible solution is to use [`GetModuleHandleEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683200.aspx) with `GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS` to find out if the address returned by `set_terminate` is a valid address in any module.

Comment: I think we can assume that if _get_terminate is null there is no pre-existing terminate handler.

Comment: Surely, but can we assume the opposite, i.e. a non-null result pointing to a valid handler? I am not as good at English to say for sure, but they say the returned value for the case of no handler "may be" NULL. Does it mean it "may be" some special non-NULL value as well?

Comment: It says that you can restore previous behaviour by callilng `set_terminate` with the return value of a previous call to `set_terminate`. That doesn't rule out "special" return values (e.g. 0xffffffff) which might be special-cased. But as long as you treat it as opaque there is no issue. Not sure why he wants to chain-call the previous one, but I don't think it is a great idea.